# RGB 24-bit resolution on 12-bit DAC

Tags: dac, display, rgb

I am looking to pass my 24-bit RGB color value through a DAC, but my resolution of the DAC is 12-bits.

1. Would I have to reduce the resolution of each channel to fit it on my 12-bit DAC?
2. Is there a way to still pass a high resolution 24-bit RGB value in multiple cycles (but it would be out of sync)?
3. Would getting a 24-bit DAC solve the issue?

Comment: 24 bit RGB generally means 8 bits for each colour channel anyway. So a 3 channel 12 bit DAC will be fine if it's fast enough.

Comment: That was my biggest concern, if there would be a noticeable difference between an 8-bit channel and a 4-bit channel.

Comment: Factoring in gamma, you actually need a 12 bit DAC to produce the brightness levels of an 8 bit color channel (unless you're driving an old fashioned CRT that does it in analog), so it sounds like you're good to go.

Comment: But wouldn't I have to load the entire RGB color into the 12-bit DAC (4 bits for each channel) or would I load the R-value (12 bits), then the G-value (12 bits), then the B-value (12 bits).

Comment: It depends on DAC. Please give DAC part number or link to datasheet. Unless it is a triple DAC meant for video, then no.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/LTC1448CN8-PBF/889523 @Justme

Comment: What are you doing with the DAC? Sending three 8 bit values into a two channel 12 bit DAC seems impossible anyway to get 3 color values out. The only thing common is that 3*8 bits equals 2*12 bits.

Comment: I am trying to create an rgb laser pulse. My thought process was 3 separate lasers for each channel and convert the digital value to the analog voltage in order to replicate the correct light intensity (0-255)

Comment: Like @BrianDrummond said, a 3 channel 12-bit DAC should be fine.

Comment: Start at the laser end of the problem and get that sorted out before you worry about the DAC.  Its likely going to be a lot more complicated than you think, and unclear that an analog level is really what you'd want anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Answering ... something, probably not the actual question which is starting to appear in little dribs and drabs in comments.

First ... this is a very slow [2-channel 12 bit DAC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1448f.pdf), with 14 microseconds settling time. That datasheet link should have been in the question.

You are trying to do something with 24-bit RGB. It's unclear exactly what, but some form of "pulse".

Now 24-bit RGB is NOT 24 bit resolution and a 24-bit ADC is not necessary or helpful. It is 3 channels of 8-bit RGB values (usually video). So you need 3 DAC channels with at least 8 bit resolution, at whatever speed you need to keep up with the input.

So on the face of it, you could use 2 of these DACs, feeding R and G to both channels of the first, and B in one channel of the other. The fact that it's a 12-bit DAC doesn't hurt (apart from generally being slower than 8-bit ones ... and 24 bit ones are much slower still ... see below) and may be an advantage if you find you need gamma correction as suggested in a comment.

BUT

and it's a big BUT...

if you expect this to keep up with the speeds required for video, forget it. It's far too slow.

If you are trying to generate a very long, low-speed pulse covering at least a whole line of a video scan, or e.g. turn a whole screen the same colour, it might do the job. But you haven't told us what the pulse is ... rise time, length, repetition rate ... so there's no way to answer that.

There is another issue : you want to control a laser with each channel (again, in comments : should be in the question). You need to know how each laser is controlled : if your laser driver expects a PWM input, driving it from a DAC makes no sense. And you haven't told us anything about that. As Chris says, start at the laser end.

Or even better, start with what your real requirements are.